# Reduce apk size

Tags: android

I am developing an android application in which there are hundreds of high quality images(512x512px to 1000x1000 px and above) and hence the apk size has become too (more than 400mb) large. So, is there a way to compress my .png images or any other way to reduce the app size. I also read about proguard but will it delete my images?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are these textures for OpenGL ES? You could use texture compression to reduce their size and improve the performance of your app. Other than that JPEG can give you better compression results at the expense of visual quality. That's a lot of pictures though. If you're going to publish on Google Play you could pack them in an APK expansion file: http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An APK with 400 MB is really huge, so you need to compress images, use these links to compress http://www.tinypng.com http://www.compresspng.com http://www.punypng.com You could also choose to load the images from server and store it in sdcard on application launch. So your application doesn't need to store images inside itself. I recommend you to store & load images from server.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to use something like [pngcrush](http://pmt.sourceforge.net/pngcrush/), to reduce their file size, or you can try to store them remotely on a server and pull them down to the device on demand and cache them (it's likely that you don't need all the images at the same time)

Answer (score 2):

**How to reduce apk size**-

1. Image Compression

   - Pre-process images-Manually optimize images in res folder using     external tools, and set cruncherEnabled to false to keep optimization.
   - Pre-process .PNG using zopflipng.
   - In android version above 4.0 WEBP images can be used.
   - For icons vector drawables is better option.
2. Code Compression

   -Use proguard to compress the bytecode in raw apk file.ClassyShark is apk explorer tool allow   to look into dex files

   - Remove resources using resConfigs.
   - Set  shrinkResource true in build.gradle file to remove unnecessary resources left by proguard.
   - ArscBlamer is tool to compress strings.(For apps which have multiple string folder for multiple android versions)

for more info about apk size visit this  [link](http://techpad4u.blogspot.in/2016/05/google-io-2016-key-highlights-android_20.html?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=share&utm_content=bloglink&utm_campaign=pageviews)

Comment: @armatita thanks for the suggestion i have made changes

Comment: if you want to compress more than 20 images in one shot you can try this online compressor it allows you to compress 50 files in one shot way2enjoy.com/compress-png

Answer (score 1):

As stated in earlier answers there are ways to compress images, but these will not take you too far. You need to change you app to dynamically download images. To save space on the user's device, you should probably let users pick which images or groups of images they want to download, instead of downloading all images.